# Automatic file downloads limited to 10 files on Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, download

I have a webpage where we generate PDFs based upon the user selection of on-page items. This causes a postback (it's an ASP.NET WebForms page) which creates the PDFs server-side. An `<a class="documentDownload">` tag is then added to the page for each item.

When the page reloads in the browser the following jQuery script is executed to automatically download the files (if the user had chosen a auto-download option):

```
var divHost = document.createElement("div");
divHost.id = "elmntDnldLinks";
divHost.style.display = "none";
document.body.appendChild(divHost);

setTimeout(function() {
    $(".documentDownload").each(function(idx, val) {

        var lnkDownload = $(val),
            save = document.createElement("a");

        save.href = lnkDownload.attr("href");
        save.download = lnkDownload.attr("download");
        save.target = "_blank";
        divHost.appendChild(save);
        save.click();
    });
}, 1000);
```

This script has a delay of 1 second, then for each .documentDownload element it creates a new `<a>` element with the same `href` attribute of the original element, appends it to a newly-added hidden element, then programmatically clicks it.

[*This strategy of creating new links and clicking those instead of clicking the original DOM elements gets around a browser security measure.*]

This works perfectly well in Firefox but Chrome never downloads more than 10 files. Why? I can see, for example, 15 links on the page and in the hidden element, but only 10 files are downloaded.

Comment: Only 10 files *in-parallel* you mean? Or does it only download 10 files and completely halts?

Comment: Yes to both your questions. The links are all clicked sequentially so they all count as separate download requests but as it takes less time to add a DOM element and click it than it takes to download a file, all the downloads are in-process at the same time. But it only downloads 10 files and then stops.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you pause for a second between each 10 downloads, all of them will work in Chrome.

I used async timeout function for this workaround:

```
function pause(msec) {
    return new Promise(
        (resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(resolve, msec || 1000);
        }
    );
}

async function downloadAll(elements) {
    var count = 0;
    for (var e in elements) {

        download(elements[e]); // your custom download code here, click or whatever

        if (++count >= 10) {
            await pause(1000);
            count = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Simple timeouts multiplied by element counter could probably work too, but I did not test it.

Comment: I faced this issue only in production env and this solution worked for me. On localhost it was working. @f2d - Any idea why it was working on localhost and why does not chrome download all files sequentially?

Comment: @ganeshdeshmukh No idea, the limits are probably probably just an educated guess to avoid bogging the client system, hanging or crashing it. If you have a lot of small files, you may better pack them on the fly in a simple ZIP with no compression and stream it to the client. If you have a lot of very large files, then it may be better to just provide a list of links and download them one by one manually, or use a dedicated download manager instead of a web-browser, or even create a torrent on the server side automatically (it will also prevent file corruption).

Answer (score 2):

Setting a 200ms delay between each download solves the problem.

Tested on Google Chrome `100.0.4896.127` (Windows, macOS)

Demo in [CodePen](https://codepen.io/hyunbinseo/pen/NWXJyZa) - 'Download multiple files' should be allowed.

```js
const downloadFileWithAnchor = () => {
  const anchor = document.createElement("a");
  anchor.href = "data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,";
  anchor.download = 'blank.txt';
  document.body.appendChild(anchor);
  anchor.click();
  document.body.removeChild(anchor);
};

const repeatCount = 20;

for (let i = 0; i < repeatCount; i += 1) {
  setTimeout(
    () => {
      downloadFileWithAnchor();
    },
    i * 200 // Delay download every 200ms
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a pause in your downloads like that

```
function sleep(milliseconds) {
    let timeStart = new Date().getTime();
    while (true) {
        let elapsedTime = new Date().getTime() - timeStart;
        if (elapsedTime > milliseconds) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
                    $("#aDescarga")[0].click();
                    $("#aDescarga").attr("href","");

                    if (i > 9) {
                        sleep(2000);
                        i = 0;
                    } else {
                        i = i + 1;
                    }
```