# Using jsPDF in Edge and Chrome only allow 10 pdfs to be created

Tags: jquery, jspdf

I'm trying to create more than 10 pdf's.  For some reason Edge and Chrome stop at 10. I can create all I want in Firefox.
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zv8kb36g//)

```
var graphOptions = { xaxis:{ min: 0, max: 600, tickSize: 50 }, yaxis:{ min: -1, max: 11, tickSize: 2 }, series:{ lines: {show: true} }, grid:{ borderWidth: 1, backgroundColor: "white" }};

plot = $.plot($("#placeholder"), [ [[0, 4],[100, 2],[200, 6],[300, 10],[400, 1],[500, 0],[600, 5]] ], graphOptions);


$("#btnGetPdf").on("click", function btnGetPdf () {
    var canvas = plot.getCanvas();
    var src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    var doc = new jsPDF('landscape');
    doc.addImage(src, 'PNG', 10, 20, 280, 150);
    doc.save('testImage1.pdf');
        doc.save('testImage2.pdf');
        doc.save('testImage3.pdf');
        doc.save('testImage4.pdf');
        doc.save('testImage5.pdf');
        doc.save('testImage6.pdf');
        doc.save('testImage7.pdf');
        doc.save('testImage8.pdf');
        doc.save('testImage9.pdf');
        doc.save('testImage10.pdf');
        doc.save('testImage11.pdf');
        doc.save('testImage12.pdf');
        doc.save('testImage13.pdf');
        doc.save('testImage14.pdf');
        doc.save('testImage15.pdf');
        doc.save('testImage16.pdf');
        doc.save('testImage17.pdf');
        doc.save('testImage18.pdf');
        doc.save('testImage1a.pdf');
        doc.save('testImage2a.pdf');
        doc.save('testImage3a.pdf');
        doc.save('testImage4a.pdf');
        doc.save('testImage5a.pdf');
        doc.save('testImage6a.pdf');
        doc.save('testImage7a.pdf');
        doc.save('testImage8a.pdf');
        doc.save('testImage9a.pdf');
        doc.save('testImage10a.pdf');
        doc.save('testImage11a.pdf');
        doc.save('testImage12a.pdf');
        doc.save('testImage13a.pdf');
        doc.save('testImage14a.pdf');
        doc.save('testImage15a.pdf');
        doc.save('testImage16a.pdf');
        doc.save('testImage17a.pdf');
        doc.save('testImage18a.pdf');
          //doc.output('dataurlnewwindow');
      });
```

I've tried in different browsers and Edge and Chrome are the ones I support, so I need to get it working.

Comment: Limit on the number of simultaneous requests. [This answer suggested a fix.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56452527/3585500)

Comment: [This answer says to pause between PDFs so you don't hit the 10 at once limit.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53841885/3585500)